# python 2.7 How to make function that is used by super and sub class with their own attributes w/o an attribute error?

Tags: python-2.7, function, class, oop, subclass

I can probably use try except function but, I am curious to know if there is a better way to do it. Here is the function.

```
class Superswag():
  def __init__(self, name, where):
    self.name = name
    self.where = where
class Real(Superswag):        
  def __init__(self, name, amt_of_buckles):
    self.name = name
    self.amt_of_buckles = 0


hat = Superswag("hat","head")
jacket = Real("Jacket",10)
def isitcool(object):
    if object.name == "coat":
            return True
    elif object.amt_of_buckles >= 5:
            return True
    else:
            return False


isitcool(hat)
isitcool(jacket)



File "XXXXXXXX", line 16, in isitcool
elif object.amt_of_buckles >= 5:
AttributeError: 'Superswag' object has no attribute 'amt_of_buckles'
```

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, found isinstance function.

```
elif isinstance(object,Real) and object.amt_of_buckles >= 5:
```